# Apache Camel endpoint to write a file AS400 FTP :

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel, ibm-midrange, ftp-client

I am trying to write a file to AS400 FTP via camel endpoint as below

```
ftp://user@host:21/QSYS.LIB/XINFT.LIB?password=password&passiveMode=true
ftp://user@host:21/QSYS.LIB/XINFT.LIB?password=password
```

But the write operation fails with the following exception

```
 Cannot change directory to: QSYS.LIB. Code: 550. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[Pipeline[[Channel[Wrap[com.privasia.edi.core.routing.exception.CustErrorHandler@2003b7bd] -> com.privasia.edi.core.routing.exception.CustErrorHandler@2003b7bd], Channel[Log(ypn-cusres-containerData-outbound)[Error in YPN CUSRES Container Schedular call.]]]]]
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: 550-Specified library does not exist or cannot be accessed.
550 Current library not changed.
 Cannot change directory to: QSYS.LIB. Code: 550
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.doChangeDirectory(FtpOperations.java:705)[218:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.changeCurrentDirectory(FtpOperations.java:683)[218:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.storeFile(FtpOperations.java:469)[218:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:249)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:151)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer.process(RemoteFileProducer.java:49)[218:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:335)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:308)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:335)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:573)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:506)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:215)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:98)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:335)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:308)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:81)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:335)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:308)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:104)[106:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.10.7]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:560)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:498)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1058)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1050)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:947)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)[:1.7.0_25]
12:14:08,512 | INFO  | CUSRES.MESSAGES] | RemoteFileProducer               | 100 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.7 | Connected and logged in to: Endpoint[ftp://user@host/QSYS.LIB/XINFT.LIB?password=******]
12:14:09,484 | WARN  | CUSRES.MESSAGES] | RemoteFileProducer               | 100 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.7 | Writing file failed with: File operation failed: 550-Specified library does not exist or cannot be accessed.
550 Current library not changed.
 Cannot change directory to: QSYS.LIB. Code: 550
12:14:09,528 | ERROR | CUSRES.MESSAGES] | pn-cusres-containerData-outbound | 100 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.7 | Error in YPN CUSRES Container Schedular call.
12:14:09,529 | ERROR | CUSRES.MESSAGES] | DefaultErrorHandler              | 100 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.7 | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-SureshHTC-PC-55500-1395804991329-1-7 on ExchangeId: ID-SureshHTC-PC-55500-1395804991329-1-6). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: 550-Specified library does not exist or cannot be accessed.
550 Current library not changed.
 Cannot change directory to: QSYS.LIB. Code: 550. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[Pipeline[[Channel[Wrap[com.privasia.edi.core.routing.exception.CustErrorHandler@2003b7bd] -> com.privasia.edi.core.routing.exception.CustErrorHandler@2003b7bd], Channel[Log(ypn-cusres-containerData-outbound)[Error in YPN CUSRES Container Schedular call.]]]]]
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: 550-Specified library does not exist or cannot be accessed.
550 Current library not changed.
 Cannot change directory to: QSYS.LIB. Code: 550
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.doChangeDirectory(FtpOperations.java:705)[218:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.changeCurrentDirectory(FtpOperations.java:683)[218:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.storeFile(FtpOperations.java:469)[218:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:249)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:151)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer.process(RemoteFileProducer.java:49)[218:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:335)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:308)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:335)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:573)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:506)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:215)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:98)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:335)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:308)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:81)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:335)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:308)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86)[100:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.7]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:104)[106:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.10.7]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:560)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:498)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1058)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1050)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:947)[104:org.springframework.jms:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)[:1.7.0_25]
```

---

I am trying via ftp client as follow

```
1. Connect to FTP Via command prompt cmd--> FTP <host> --> username --> <pwd>
2. Check the current working lib the default lib is QGPL
3. Change to lib using cd "XINFT"
4. Change the mode to Ascii
5. Put the file.
```

Its working fine.

---

But i am unable to achieve the same via camel endpoint.

Comment: If you use a simple Windows or Linux FTP command-line client and enter `cd /QSYS.LIB/XFNLT.LIB` as the first FTP command after logging in, does it succeed? I wouldn't expect a NAMEFMT issue because I wouldn't expect Apache Camel to send anything in NAMEFMT 0 before your actual request. The apparent error also doesn't seem to fit; but it is indeed a possibility.

Comment: Hmmm... looking again, a NAMEFMT test is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are more than likely running into a [NAMEFMT](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaiq/rzaiqftpconvn.htm) issue.  The FTP component is probably executing a command prior to the `cd` which disables automatic [NAMEFMT](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaiq/rzaiqftpconvn.htm) selection.  A trace of the ftp session should help identify the issue.

Try forcing `NAMEFMT 1` with the `siteCommand` option in the URI:

```
ftp://user@host:21/QSYS.LIB/XINFT.LIB?password=password&passiveMode=true&siteCommand=namefmt%201
```

Comment: I tried with siteCommand=namefmt 1 but still issue is there :(.... ftp://user@host:21/QSYS.LIB/XINFT.LIB?passiveMode=true&password=******&runLoggingLevel=INFO&siteCommand=namefmt+1

Comment: ftp://user@host:port/QSYS/XINFT?password=*****&amp;passiveMode=true&amp;runLoggingLevel=INFO&amp;siteCommand=NAMEFMT 0 - This how i am able to write the file to required location.