# Camel FTP file automation

Tags: java, apache, ftp, apache-camel

I have two win2008 R2 server.When trying to transfer file through Apache Camel I am getting this error-

```
16:27:27,533 94053 [Camel (camelContext) thread #1 -ftp:// ctsftp@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx/ftproot] WARN  org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFilePollingConsumerPollStrategy  - Consumer FtpConsumer[ftp:// ctsftp@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx/ftproot?disconnect=true&exclusiveReadLockStrategy=%23FTPFileLockStrategy&filter=%23ResAndAckFilter&idempotent=true&idempotentRepository=%23ResAndAckStore&localWorkDirectory=C:/temp&passiveMode=true&password=******] could not poll endpoint: Endpoint[ftp:// ctsftp@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx/ftproot?disconnect=true&exclusiveReadLockStrategy=%23FTPFileLockStrategy&filter=%23ResAndAckFilter&idempotent=true&idempotentRepository=%23ResAndAckStore&localWorkDirectory=C:/temp&passiveMode=true&password=******] caused by: File operation failed: 550 Permission denied
 Cannot change directory to: /. Code: 550
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: 550 Permission denied
 Cannot change directory to: /. Code: 550
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.doChangeDirectory(FtpOperations.java:628)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.changeCurrentDirectory(FtpOperations.java:591)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer.pollDirectory(FtpConsumer.java:53)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:100)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:90)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my route details -

```
from uri="ftp://ftpuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx/ftproot?filter=#ResAndAckFilter&amp;exclusiveReadLockStrategy=#FTPFileLockStrategy&amp;idempotent=true&amp;idempotentRepository=#ResAndAckStore&amp;localWorkDirectory=C:/temp&amp;passiveMode=true&amp;disconnect=true&amp;password=abcd" />
            <to uri="file://F:/Incoming?tempPrefix=PART_"
```

DFile versions are as below-
                camel-core-2.9.2,
        camel-ftp-2.9.2,
        commons-net-2.2

Ftpuser has admin prviledges and all the directory has read-wrilte-xecute privildge for user.

Comment: Are you able to manually log to the FTP server root directory and change the current directory with `cd ftproot`? If it is not a `stepwise` problem, perhaps you run into a NAMEFMT problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651690/apache-camel-endpoint-to-write-a-file-as400-ftp?

Answer (score 2):

Error messsage implies that the user does not have access to the root directory /. 
Wild guess, try adding the option stepwise=false.
Read more about stepwise here: http://camel.apache.org/ftp.html

Comment: in my from uri I have added like this-"ftp://ftpuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx/ftproot?filter=#ResAndAckFilter&amp;exclusiveReadLockStrategy=#FTPFileLockStrategy&amp;idempotent=true&amp;idempotentRepository=#ResAndAckStore&amp;localWorkDirectory=C:/temp&amp;passiveMode=true&amp;disconnect=true&amp;password=abcd;stepwise=false"     but it giving me invalid userid/password

Comment: Well, then your login is probably wrong? Exception says "thread #1 -ftp:// ctsftp@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx". Is the username really starting with a space ?

Comment: It is without space in config file.I am trying to modify privileges in  destination location as hit and trial method.

Comment: Also when I am removing stepwise=false from to uri I am getting my old error.

Comment: Adding stepwise=false should not affect your login. Can you please post your full route including the stepwise addition. Would probably help also if you could change log level to info/debug and repost the log with more details on what happens before the exception

Answer (score 0):

After giving administrator prviledge to ftpuser as well host priviledge We made this work.My destination folder structure was like this /ftproot/abcd. So we made ftproot as home directory (i.e whenever I am logging in using filezilla or commandline it should land me on /ftproot) and after logging in I can go one directory up by (if i use cd .. in ftproot then it should take me to /).For this we gave admin priviledge and host priviledge to ftpuser.